# Sorting inner array for a string

Tags: javascript

Both attempts fail to sort the inner arrays:

```
a=[['c'],['b']]
a.sort(function(a,b){a[0]<b[0]}) // returns c,b
console.log(JSON.stringify(a))
a.sort(function(a,b){a[0]>b[0]}) // returns c,b
console.log(JSON.stringify(a))
```

What am I doing wrong?  Thank you!

http://jsfiddle.net/0w7t3ov2/

Comment: The comparison function is supposed to return a number, not `true` or `false`.

Comment: Using `a[0]<b[0]?1:-1` did not work either: http://jsfiddle.net/0w7t3ov2/1/

Comment: You don't have `return` in any of your functions.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/0w7t3ov2/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you pass to `.sort()` needs to return an integer, not a boolean. The integer should be less than zero if the first argument should come before the second in the sort order; greater than zero if it should come after; and zero if they're equal.

So, in your case:

```
a.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a[0] < b[0] ? -1 :
         a[0] > b[0] ? 1 :
         0;
});
```